# Permissions with the /sys filesystem

Tags: linux, debian

In Ubuntu the permissions for the /sys filesystem are much more lax than on a default Debian install. If I have a program trying to access /sys/class/net/eth0 on Ubuntu there is no issue, but in Debian the permissions are locked down.

I understand now that /sys is created as a virtual space for querying/updating kernel values, but I can't figure out how to modify the permissions that /sys gets created with. Is it a configuration option when compiling the kernel? Can it be modified with tools like sysfsutils?

Edit: I have realized that my installation of Debian might have been modified from the server host I am using. Any ideas on how they modified the permissions of the directory?

`total 4
dr-xr-xr-x  11 root root    0 Oct  2 11:43 .
drwxr-xr-x  22 root root 4096 Sep 23 13:32 ..
drwx------   2 root root    0 Oct  2 11:43 block
drwx------  28 root root    0 Oct  2 11:43 bus
drwx------  67 root root    0 Oct  2 11:43 class
drwx------   4 root root    0 Oct  2 11:43 dev
drwxr-xr-x  18 root root    0 Oct  2 11:43 devices
drwx------   4 root root    0 Oct  2 11:43 firmware
drwxr-xr-x  11 root root    0 Oct  2 11:43 fs
drwx------  10 root root    0 Oct  2 11:43 kernel
drwx------ 196 root root    0 Oct  2 11:43 module`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the Provider. After installing the stock kernel things started functioning correctly.

I used [this](https://forum.ovh.co.uk/showthread.php?5616-Standard-Kernels-with-Ubuntu-Debianhttps://forum.ovh.co.uk/showthread.php?5616-Standard-Kernels-with-Ubuntu-Debian) thread for changing the default GRUB selection.